# SharePoint Online + MS Flow (Request manager approval for leave requests)

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, flow

I'm currently interested in utilizing this MS Flow: https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/906bdcc238bb49f19879ab62a88f3aa7/request-manager-approval-for-leave-requests/

I'd like to scale this to be enterprise wide, meaning this Flow would be used across all departments. My biggest requirement is that when the leave request is approved, it can somehow be shown on the department calendar. Please keep in mind that i'd like for each department to have their own calendar.

Is this possible? From reading the description and doing research online, it seems like this workflow doesn't publish if the request was accepted/denied. As far as I know, it only shows the results in the requestor's email.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have two requirements:

1. Scale the request process to work among multiple departments
2. Create events on department calendars for approved requests

Yes, this is possible, but you will need to modify the Flow template to get the desired result. Fortunately this is fairly simple and only requires a few additional actions.

**Also**, if you are going to use this Flow with a large population, be cognizant of the number of [Flow runs](https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/) you have in your tenant. If you go over your allotted quantity of runs then the flow will stop working until the next billing cycle.

Anyway, to create events for approved requests on multiple department calendar, you will need some way to look up the location of each calendar by department name. So you may need to create, for example, a lookup list in SharePoint to match department names to site URL's & list names, etc.

(In the Flow you would put these actions inside the `If yes` branch of the condition.)
[image]

The department of the user who made the request is automatically supplied by Flow, so all you have to do is use a `Get Items` action and Filter on that value:
[image: Get items action]

After this action you can use values from the lookup in subsequent actions.

If your department calendars are in SharePoint Online then you would want to use the **Create Item** action, and then fill in the details of the event under *Advanced Options*.
[image: Create List Item action in Flow]

If instead you use Exchange to host department calendars then you would use the Create Event (V2) action instead. 
[image]

In either case, you must make sure that the user account that authorizes these action also has sufficient access to all department calendars, wherever they are. You can find which account is associated with each action by clicking on the ellipsis in the upper right corner of the action: 
[image: Determine which account is authorizing the action]